# How to feed strange characters to javaScript?

Tags: javascript, replace

I am using code like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('toReplace', 'replacement');
```

It works for strings in standard English alphabet. However, I would like to replace a word which contains a strange east-European character 'š'. It has an UTF decimal code 154. How to do it?

Comment: Supply the character as a Unicode string?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks for marking the question as duplicate.